# Spring AOP Pointcut syntax for AND, OR and NOT

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I'm having trouble with a pointcut definition in Spring (version 2.5.6). I'm trying to intercept all method calls to a class, except for a given method (someMethod in the example below).

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor
         pointcut="execution(* x.y.z.ClassName.*(..)) AND NOT
                   execution(* x.y.x.ClassName.someMethod(..))"
    />
</aop:config>
```

However, the interceptor is invoked for someMethod as well.

Then I tried this:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor
         pointcut="execution(* x.y.z.ClassName.(* AND NOT someMethod)(..)) )"
    />
</aop:config>
```

But this does not compile as it is not valid syntax (I get a BeanCreationException).

Can anybody give any tips?

Comment: Have you considered writing the aspect logic with @AspectJ style instead? It's much simpler and more powerful to write the aspect logic with Java. Especially if you're using Eclipse with the AJDT plugin.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

i know its probably a bit late at this stage but ive been having the same issue and I resolved it by escaping the ampersand chars so its `&amp;&amp; !` instead of 'AND NOT' or '&& !'.
I'm doing this in the xml file

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="blah" expression="execution(* com.disney.goofy..*.*(..)) &amp;&amp; !@annotation(com.disney.goofy.NonDisneyCharacter)"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="transAdvice" pointcut-ref="blah"/>
</aop:config>
```

This applies the advice to all methods executed in com.disney.goofy and that are not annotated with NonDisneyCharacter

Answer (score 6):

This should work ([spring AOP reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-combining)):

```
pointcut="execution(* x.y.z.ClassName.*(..))
          && !execution(* x.y.x.ClassName.someMethod(..))"
```

Comment: It doesn't work I'm afraid. Note that the Spring reference says && > AND and ! > Not in XML-files. Thanks for the tip anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using spring 2.5.6 and was having a similar problem with **OR** not working, but **AND** *was* working. It turns out that **or** (in lowercase) *does* work, so there is clearly a bug in that code.

It is interesting that the proper aspectJ syntax is **&&**, **||**, and **!**, but the and/or/not syntax was added by spring to make working in xml easier. From the manual:

> When combining pointcut
>   sub-expressions, '&&' is awkward
>   within an XML document, and so the
>   keywords 'and', 'or' and 'not' can be
>   used in place of '&&', '||' and '!'
>   respectively.

I would guess that since **&&** is the only one that is *actually* awkward in xml (there is nothing difficult about putting | or ! in xml) then **AND** is the only one that was properly tested