# Spring AOP Pointcut composition does not work in JBoss

Tags: spring, jboss, aop, spring-aop

I have a following AOP pointcut:

```html
<aop:config>
     <aop:pointcut id="myPointcut"
        expression="execution(* com.company.IModule..*(..))
        and !execution(* com.company.IModule.getMethod1(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="myPointcut" />  
</aop:config>
```

This works in Weblogic, but fails in JBoss with the exception:

```html
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.company.IModule [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
```

I tried to replace 'and' with '&amp;&amp;' as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2789579/1110054) but the result was the same.

If I remove composition and just leave one execution statement it works fine.

JBoss EAP 6.4.0 
Weblogic 10.3.6 
Java 1.7.0_51 
Spring 3.2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Weblogic is case insensitive, but JBoss only accepts uppercase 'AND'.